# непонятная ошибка 401, которая пропадает после рестарта приложения

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, settimeout

Всем привет.
Есть приложение на express. В приложении пытаюсь опрашивать сторонний апи, отправляя каждые 2 минуты несколько запросов. Авторизация по токену, который точно валиден. Для запросов использую fetch. Функция отправляющая запросы, инициируется через setTimeout.
После старта приложения какое-то время все работает нормально и получаю нормальные ответы. Через какое-то время, сторонний апи начинает отвечать ошибкой 401. Думал, что апи так защищается от слишком частых запросов, поэтому в setTimeout встроил механизм увеличения промежутка между запросами в случае получения ошибки 401. Каждый раз увеличиваю на 1 минуту.
Вчера вечером запустил приложение с мыслью, что оно подберет промежуток между запросами, который позволит не получать ошибку. В результате за ночь промежуток между запросами дорос до 30 минут, но ошибки так и поступали. Перезапустил приложение и ситуация повторилась. Какое-то время запросы проходили, а потом опять пошли ошибки и опять перезагрузка решила проблему на время.

Из этого делаю вывод (хотя может быть я и ошибаюсь) что это какая-то самозащита стороннего апи от слишком частых запросов, которая завязана не на частоту и количество запросов, а на что-то другое.
Соответственно вопрос.
В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: Пробуй узнать то "разрешенное" количество запросов... Если оно стабильно одинаковое - значит твое предположение верное. Пробуй узнать у владельцев того АПИ почему такое происходит, может они тебе чего подскажут...

Comment: Какая-то авторизация есть у этого АПИ? Может просто текен помирает, а обновления не происходит...

Comment: @ksa Спасибо тебе. :) Так и было

Answer (score 0):

Токен был ограничен по времени, а обновления не происходило.
Спасибо @ksa за то что натолкнул на мысль.